# Can the update interval of ModalOperatorTimer be changed during the loop?

Tags: python, scripting

I created the following script.

```
import bpy

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"
    loop_count = 0
    loop_fps = 10
    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            print(self.loop_count)
            self.loop_count = self.loop_count + 1
            if self.loop_count > 150:
                self.loop_fps = 1

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(1/self.loop_fps, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

First, count 10 times per second.

When the count exceeds 150 counts, the value of self.loop_fps is changed to 1.

In other words, after the 150th count, I only want to turn the loop once per second.

However, this script does not work, and it runs 10 times a second after the 150th count.

Can the update interval of ModalOperatorTimer be changed during the loop?

Comment: I don't think so.  For case in question could stop current and invoke a new modal (pass the timing as property on invoke).  Otherwise consider https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html  Alternatively instead of changing timer click, count 10 timer events (ie 10 x 0.1 seconds = 1 second) to do anything after certain time.

Comment: I read the documentation you posted and found that I could create the features I wanted. Thank you very much.